# How to unit test page redirection using jsdom, localhost is 'blank'

Tags: unit-testing, redirect, mocha.js, chai, jsdom

I have a function that its purpose is to redirect to pageA if triggered by the user, otherwise redirect to pageB;

When I am unit testing the function

```
        const expected = `${host}/pageA`;

        redirect(true); // calling the redirect function
        const actual = window.location;
        expect(actual).to.equal(expected);
```

fails because 'blank/pageA' is not 'http://localhost:5401/pageA'

It looks like window.location has a 'blank' host, why does this happen? How do I fix this?
I am using jsdom, mocha, chai.

My set up looks like this:

```
    let originalWindow = global.window,
    host = 'https://localhost:5401';

    beforeEach(() => {
        global.window = {
            location: {
                href: "https://localhost:5401/pageA/2020"
            }
        };
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        global.window = originalWindow;
    });
```

Comment: Please make this into a [mcve]. The problem may be elsewhere than in the code you show.